# Is there any way to publish files from an Azure Hosted Agent? (release not build pipeline)

Tags: docker, azure-devops, cypress

I'm using a Release Pipeline to execute Cypress tests in a docker container.  I've gotten to the point where I have been able to push the /videos folder outside the container to the agent itself.

I've tried using the Publish Artifacts task but it only seems to apply to a Build Pipeline and I'm using a Release Pipeline since we need an environment to execute the tests against.

Is there some other pipeline task or something I'm missing that I can use now to publish this folder since I'd like to be able to view the videos for debugging purposes?

Comment: You get the files out of the container after it runs the same way you would with any other container: `docker cp`. Then you publish artifacts the same way you'd publish any other artifacts: The Publish Artifacts task.

Comment: @DanielMann I've already got the new directory copied to the Ubuntu Agent from docker.  I actually tried the publish task but it's a release pipeline not a build.  It's telling me this task needs to be run in a build

Comment: @James Gooding Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> I actually tried the publish task but it's a release pipeline not a
>   build.

For this issue , you can try this extension: [Publish and Download Artifacts from Release Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.ReleaseArtifacts&targetId=0933e8b2-f504-4b7e-9e9e-ce303b05ea59)

The tasks contained in this package allow on one side to upload files to the logs of the release to create Release Artifacts. Another task allows to fetch those artifacts again, for example if they are needed in a different agent phase.

[image]

**Publish Release Artifact Task :**

The Publish Release Artifact Task is very straight forward and only needs one parameter to work properly. Specify the path to the file or the folder you want to have uploaded to the logs.

In case a folder is specified, this folder will be zipped and is available later on as foldername.zip in the logs.